# How to preview dynamically uploaded images before upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand why I can't preview multiple images that are in different divs.

I am appending a new div that includes a new input for a file upload, sort of a section for a set of instructions, each has it's own image.

When I try uploading, the preview only works for the first div, not the rest. I thought the on event handler would work, but it does not.

```js
$('.instructions__add-new').on('click', function() {
    $('.instructions__append-inputs').append('<div class="instructions__container"><img id="instructionsImg" src=""><input type="file" class="instructions__image-input" name="recipe_instructions_image[]" onchange="document.getElementById("instructionsImg").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])"></div><div class="instructions__append-inputs"></div>');
});
```

```css
#instructionsImg {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="instructions__container">
    <img id="instructionsImg" src="">
    <input type="file" class="instructions__image-input" name="recipe_instructions_image[]" onchange="document.getElementById('instructionsImg').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
</div>
<div class="instructions__append-inputs"></div>
<div class="instructions__add-new">+ New Instruction</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("instructionsImg")` will select the first Element with that ID which is why element's need to have unique IDs. You are not using unique id's for each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a small change, it will work. Instead of find it using `previousSibling` selector in javascript. 
https://jsfiddle.net/e4wez2d1/1/

```
$('.instructions__add-new').on('click', function() {
  $('.instructions__append-inputs').append('<div class="instructions__container"><img id="instructionsImg" src=""><input type="file" class="instructions__image-input" name="recipe_instructions_image[]" onchange="this.previousSibling.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])"></div><div class="instructions__append-inputs"></div>');
});
```

Comment: I've started learning about xpath recently and it didn't come to mind that it could be used this way too. Thank you. If anyone ever runs into this issue, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_previoussibling.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your JQuery script, check your quotes in your string.

```
onchange = " document ( " quote error " ) "
```

Use antislash quotes. Like  **\"**

Answer (score 0):

From your code, i think you should use the event of jquery for input changing.

```
$('input.instructions__image-input').on('change',function(){
    var divParent = $(this).closest("div.instructions__container");
    $("#instructionsImg",divParent).attr("src",window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])) ;
});
```